# HTTP_21 - OAuth2 authentication failed. Please make sure the credentials are valid

Tags: google-realtime-api, streamsets

I'm implementing Google Analytics Api with StreamSet to stream real-time stats.I have given private key and jwt token correctly but always getting the same error "HTTP_21 - OAuth2 authentication failed. Please make sure the credentials are valid."
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The StreamSets Slack channel or Google Group might be good places to ask about this - see https://streamsets.com/community/

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?